# iMacros: How can I click a link in with a specific attribute?

Tags: imacros

In an iMacros script, how can you trigger a click on a link with a specific attribute? In this case, the link I would like to have clicked has a class of "i-project":

```
<div  data-explore-index="1" >

        <div class="i-project-card ">
            <a href="/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ">
                <span ></span>

            </a>
            <a href="blablabla" class="i-project">
                <img src="https://blabla.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>



    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to select this link based upon its CLASS attribute:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:i-project
```